# Change Heading Number copied from another document

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I change the Heading Number with VBA code?

For example, "1.1 Computer system"
I'd like to change "1.1" to "1.2".

I can read it with:

```
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
```

I can't find a way to change it.

1. Basic Function Test

1.1. LED Function Test Purpose: To make sure all the LED Functions are working as the Product Specification Resource Requirements:

The context is shown above. Sometimes, I copy from another document. The pasted heading number is not correct.

I tried to record the macro but the recorded macro is empty.

Comment: Is it possible provide some "context" or a sample document? This will assist anyone who might be able to help you.

Comment: Did you try recording a macro when you do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

To force Heading 2 to start the numbering from 1.2, all you need is:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2).ListTemplate.ListLevels(2).StartAt = 2
```

Your update shows you're trying to do something quite different, however.

The only reliable way to retain the original numbering when copying/pasting between documents is to either:

- convert the source numbering to static text before copying; or
- paste the copied content as unformatted text.